# Creating a Networkx Graph from a csv file

Tags: python, networkx

how can I make a graph from a csv file and make a correlation so that two provinces are connected when they present a correlation greater than 0.8?

the csv file `covid19_US_cases.csv` is shown below:

[image]

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
covid_US_cases = pd.read_csv('covid19_US_cases.csv') 
G_covid_US_cases = nx.Graph ()
plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 10))
graph_pos = nx.spring_layout(G_covid_US_cases)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G_covid_US_cases, graph_pos, edge_color='k', `enter code here`alpha=0.3)
a = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G_covid_US_cases, graph_pos, font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
```

[image]

Comment: English please.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: yes i tried this code

Comment: Break this down into discrete steps. First step: read in your CSV file and generate the edge list. Next step: feed your edge and node lists to networkx...

Comment: Currently, it is unclear between what you want to calculate the correlation. Afterwards you need to filter and then turn it into a graph, e.g. [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html?highlight=pandas#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist)